# KeyError in Django form kwargs

Tags: django

```
def user_info(request, template_name='social/retrieve_user_data.html', username=None):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, user)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        print('not post')
        form = UserInfoForm(user)


    return render_to_response(template_name, RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
    }))


class UserInfoForm(forms.Form):


    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(UserInfoForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

This is producing a KeyError with exception value u'user'. What is wrong here? In both cases, form is initialized with a valid value of user. Why am I getting a keyerror>

Comment: If you want to access form field, you should use `self.cleaned_data` dictionary after calling `super` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not passing the user as a keyword argument in either the if or the else block. It should be:

```
form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, user=user)
```

and:

```
form = UserInfoForm(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `func(foo=bar)`can put `{"foo":bar}` into `kwargs` dictionary! According to  your code  `form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, user)`,you can use `self.user = args[1]` to capture `user`.